# Discord.js remember user input for later use (aka args)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am completely new to programming and to JS. All I want is the following:

User uses command: ?remember Mike
and then when he uses ?get command the output should be like this:
Bot: You said "Mike"

So basically saving an argument from a command (in a var or let?) for later use when the user asks for it back.

That's it! :)

Comment: Use a database 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it permanently, you should use a database.

But if you want to store the input until you shut down the bot, you should create an array, and when `?remember Mike` is called, you can push the input like this:

```js
array.push({"id":message_variable.author.id,"input":input_variable}); //Remember input
```

And when `?get` is called, you can use the following to send the remembered input:

```js
let remembered = array.find(i => i.id === message_variable.author.id); //Get input
//Check if anything was remembered
if(!!remembered) message_variable.channel.send(`You said "${remembered.input}"`;
else message_variable.channel.send("There is nothing to remember!");
```

(This might not be the best approach, but it should work unless I made a mistake)